# Need to save multiple entities within a grid. Could I somehow use ArrayLists inside twodimensional Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I'm working on particle physics simulation using Java Processing where I now needs to keep track on what entities (objects with x and y coordinate) exists at certain parts of the screen. I'd also need to be able to know the cells' position to eachother as to do such as checking for collision between objects in a cell and bordering cells.

What's the best way to implement such a system? Is it somehow possible to put an ArrayList inside an array of arrays (2D-array)? Cause I didn't seem to manage to put lists inside arrays when I tried. Any better way to do it?

Comment: You actually dont need 2D array at all, just an ArrayList containing all your entities have all the information you need. The biggest problem is complexity, if everything can colide with everything, you have O(n^2).

Comment: Yes, I know I don't _actually_ need it to do collision checks.
I've already got that working. However, the checks do grow exponentionally which becomes a pain when I try to simulate hundreds of particles. Thus the idea is that upon start, the space is divided into a grid. Then for collision checking, each grid will have its particles added to an arraylist. Then collision is checked between all particles in the same grid and particles in adjacent grids, reducing the checks from n^2 to a^2 + b^2 + c^2 ... whereas a, b, c and so on are much smaller numbers.

Comment: Yeah, the dividing into grids is common way to reduce complexity of tasks like this, its good approach. You can have array of type "arraylist", I do not see any problem there :)

Comment: I would only recommend to create a class, which will wrap functionality of this grid. Rather than accessing this array directly like `myGrid[x][y]` it is better to have somethine like this `myGrid.getGridAtPosition(x,y)`, it will save you a lot troubles in future.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing now. Got myself a GridKeeper class that stores an ArrayList of class GridCell which maintains an arraylist of entities. Might as well use ArrayLists all the way and get gridwise position by multiplying and adding a bit here and there.

Comment: Well, I think you are doing it right :). Even modern engines do it similar (the only difference is, they do not end up by separate space into grids, they separate grids into grids several times, maybe you should think about it too, if you have a lot particles)